# How do I use an array and add to it in an object factory?

Tags: javascript

```
function player_factory(name, regions) {
        this.name = name;
        this.regions = regions;
    }

var player_1 = new player_factory('player 1', 'land 1');
```

I would like to add additional regions to player_1.regions like you do with an array using the push function and I would like to be able to loop through the values, not replace the one value that it stores.

Comment: So make it an array? Your question is quite unclear, perhaps show your attempts?

Comment: Currently there's no code that replaces the one value it stores anyway.

Comment: You've *called* this a factory, but its using a traditional [constructor function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new) (which would typically be written using [a class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/class) in modern code). It doesn't look like the factory pattern at all.

Comment: You *could* call it like `player_factory('player 1', ['land 1'])` Wouldn't fix the fact that you're calling it a factory when it's not, but it would give you the ability to do `player_1.regions.push('land 2')` to add regions...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use argument spread syntax and `Array::flat()` to provide regions in any form in the constructor and having them as an array in the end:

```js
function player_factory(name, ...regions) {
        this.name = name;
        this.regions = regions.flat();
    }

var player_1 = new player_factory('player 1', 'land 1', 'land 2', ['land 3']);
player_1.regions.push('land 4', 'land 5');

for(const region of player_1.regions){
  console.log(region);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, the ... in front of the region in the constructor did it.

Answer (score 1):

Is that what you wanted?

```js
function player_factory(name, regions) {
  this.name = name;
  this.regions = [regions];
}

var player_1 = new player_factory('player 1', 'land 1');
player_1.regions.push('123')
console.log(player_1)
```